# iptables blocking me to telnet to outside server on port 80

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, tcp, iptables

I have been trying to telnet on one outside server on port 80.

**With iptables on:**

```
telnet XYZ 80
Trying XYZ...
Connected to XYZ.
Escape character is '^]'.
qwer (here i type some characters)
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 03 Sep 2013 16:58:31 GMT
Connection: close

0

Connection closed by foreign host.
```

**With iptables off:**

```
telnet XYZ 80
Trying XYZ...
Connected to XYZ.
Escape character is '^]'.
qwer (here i type some characters)

Getting back html response (It's working here, with iptables off)
```

**Output of:**
    iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             abcd                state NEW tcp dpt:http

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And in  /etc/iptables.conf file, I have done port forwarding (for security concerns redirecting 80 port incoming web traffic to Apache 8080 port and vice versa) as:

```
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2:100]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [20:1650]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [20:1650]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080 
COMMIT
```

what entry to do in iptables to make telnet on  XYZ server on port 80 working, as it's doing fine if i keep my iptables off?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused. You're trying to telnet to a http server? Or are you trying to put your telnet server on port 80? Where does port 8080 come into this?